# Could not start virtuoso on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtuoso

I have installed opensource virtuoso on windows server 2003.

I followed all the instructions given on the link [openlinksw](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSUsageWindows) even the service instance has been created i can see the service list but whenever I'm trying to start the service it's giving me following error:

> could not start Open link virtuoso server "Virt" service on local
>   computer. Error 193:0xc1.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What is the actual command you are running to start the Virtuoso Server and where is this being run from ?

Please checking the "virtuoso.log" file in the "database" directory of your installation to see why it might be failing to start.

The simplest way to try and start Virtuoso to verify base operabiity is to run the following command from the "database" directory of your installation from a command prompt:

..\virtuoso-t -f

which will start it in foreground debug mode and you can see the startup attempt in progress ...